# Taking control over window pop up to save a .zip file

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

How to take the control on window popup for saving a .zip file in window machine for firefox in java with selenium web-driver.

Comment: Selenium does not handle modal dialogs. You need to use something else, like AutoIt.

Answer (score 0):

We use a Robot class for this purpose (java.awt.Robot).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: Welcome to SO! Adding some guidance/insight, apart from the link, might help more.